# Redirect exact wordpress search to page

Tags: php, wordpress, search

Im trying to get a searchform to redirect instantly to the desired page if the search query is an exact match with a page title. I have found this piece of code which comes pretty close, but i fail to see why its not working like it should.

This is in my functions.php

```
// Redirect on exact match
function lab_title_match() {
    if (is_search()) {
        global $wp_query,$wpdb;
        $s_str = $wp_query->query_vars['s'];
        $m = $wpdb->get_var($wpdb->prepare("SELECT ID FROM {$wpdb->posts} WHERE post_title = %s",$s_str));
        if (!empty($m)) {
            wp_safe_redirect(get_permalink($m));
            exit();
        }
    }
}
add_filter('pre_get_posts','lab_title_match');
```

This results in a redirect to domain.com/keyword/keyword/ instead of just domein.com/keyword/. I rewrote this multiple times while still getting the same result, so its probably me.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

I resolved it another way. Instead of an exact search i redirect as long as there is only 1 result.

```
// Redirect on 1 result
add_action('template_redirect', 'lab_redirect');
function lab_redirect() {
if (is_search()) {
    global $wp_query;
    if ($wp_query->post_count == 1) {
        wp_redirect( get_permalink( $wp_query->posts['0']->ID ) );
    }
}
}
```

Comment: [wp_redirect](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_redirect/) does not exit automatically, and should almost always be followed by a call to `exit;`